# Mocha testing TypeScript with types defined in global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, mocha.js

I'm currently putting together a test framework for a legacy application that has many `types.ts` files that define types without any imports/exports in the top level of the file. For example, we have a `Pills/types.ts` file that contains only

```
interface Pills {
 id: number,
 // more properties
}
```

[According to the TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), without an imports/exports, the file is considered a module and is a part of the global scope. Any file that uses the `Pills` type uses it without explicitly importing the type. This currently works fine in our web application, which is running as a `webpack` bundle.

However, when I try to run a test using `mocha`, which runs on NodeJS, I get the following error:

```
app/javascript/components/HardwareTestReports/table.tsx(18,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Pill'.
app/javascript/components/HardwareTestReports/table.tsx(106,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Pill'.
```

Is this because `mocha` runs on NodeJS, which require files to explicitly declare exports/imports?

My `.tsconfig` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es7", "dom", "esnext"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "vendor", "public", "test"],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

My package.json has the following test script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "TS_NODE_PROJECT='./tsconfig.json' mocha -r ts-node/register -r esm test/**/*.ts"
  },
```

Is this because `mocha` runs on NodeJS, which require files to explicitly declare exports/imports?

Refactoring the `types.ts` files to explicitly import/export their types is not currently an option - we have many intertwined types, and updating each file to contain imports/exports would involve touching almost every file in the codebase - definitely a longer term project to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `tsconfig` is used for the tests only you can tell ts-node to include custom types:

In `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es7", "dom", "esnext"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "vendor", "public", "test"],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "files": ["Pills/types.ts"] // WHere you keep the types
  "include": ["test/**/*.ts"] // Wherever you keep your tests
}
```